# $rootScope not working - value not appearing in view

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am following the Lynda.com Building a data-driven app with angularjs.

`authentication.js` has `$rootScope.currentUser` assigned the value of the user from Firebase and in `index.html` it is supposed to display `{{currentUser.firstname}}`. The user is logged in and the values are correct in Firebase, However nothing is displayed on the page.

```
authentication.js
myApp.factory('Authentication', function($firebase,
  $firebaseAuth, $routeParams, $rootScope, $location, FIREBASE_URL) {

  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  auth.$onAuth(function(authUser){
    if(authUser) {
        var user = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + authUser.uid);
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;

        console.log("logged in as:", authUser.uid);
        //console.log($scope.currentUser);
    }else{
        console.log("logged out");
        $rootScope.currentUser = '';
    }
  });

  //Temporary object
  var myObject = {

    login: function(user) {
      return auth.$authWithPassword({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }); //authWithPassword
    }, //login

    register: function(user) {
      return auth.$createUser({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }).then(function(regUser) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'users');
        var firebaseUsers = $firebase(ref);

        var userInfo = {
          date : Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          regUser : regUser.uid,
          firstname: user.firstname,
          lastname : user.lastname,
          email: user.email
        }; //user info

        firebaseUsers.child(regUser.uid).set(userInfo);
      }); //promise
    } //register

  }; //myObject
  return myObject;
}); //myApp Factory

index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Data</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/meetings.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/registration.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/authentication.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="cf" ng-include="'views/nav.html'">

        </nav>
    </header>
<div class="page">
    <div class="userinfo" ng-show="currentUser">
    <span class="userinfo">Hi {{ currentUser.firstname }}</span>
 </div>   
  <main class="cf" ng-view>

  </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.
EDITED.

@Scott Selby. Thanks for your suggestion however I still don't get the firstname in the view.
making `$rootScope.currentUser = authUser` I can `console.log($rootScope.currentUser);` as:

```
Object {provider: "password", uid: "simplelogin:11", token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2IjowLCJkI…wNDZ9.6eMzLZAVhOFuU8U-gl4MlsoUSrbs5FvlzGqFu-Go4S4", password: Object, auth: Object…}
```

Despite Firebase having users/

```
simplelogin:11
 date: 
 email: 
 firstname: 
 lastname: 
 regUser:
```

I can only access the uid from authUser and therefore currentUser. 
So I can pass currentUser.uid to the view but not currentUser.firstname

Comment: I've never used FireBase,  but it looks like from briefly looking at their docs that you have to actually deiign the user object types and tell firebase what they are and insert them yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy! was I suffering from brain-melt! I was missing $firebaseObject as below:

```
if(authUser) {

        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + authUser.uid);
      var user = $firebaseObject(ref);
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;

    }else{

        $rootScope.currentUser = '';
    }
```

Being new to Firebase and having discovered that they had recently replaced $asObject() with the renamed $firebaseObject service. I had removed the $asObject without substituting the $firebaseObject.
So now it works and I am happy.